# Can't unserstand how this example work. lastIndexOf() Method

Tags: javascript, substring, lastindexof

I was looking at this example that get the name of a file after you select it in your pc.

I writing becuase I don't understand, how in this case `lastIndexOf()` works!

```
<script>
        $('#browseFile').change(function() {
            var filename = $(this).val();
            var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
            if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
            }
            $('#filename').val(filename);
       });
</script>
```

I know that lastIndexOf count how many chars you have before a specified string so for example:

```
var phrase = "look at the sea";
var result phrase.lastIndexOf("sea");
```

will return 13, but why in the first example I posted  `if (lastIndex >= 0)` then we know the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
```

What this does is to find the last backslash. If one exists (`if (lastIndex >= 0)`), then we remove everything leading up to it using `substring`. In other words, the code removes the path before a file name.

Edit: I'm an idiot and messed up the `substring` syntax. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot so  substring get the entire path and remove it from the stering? Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: substring(index);   substring function  create the new string from the index which you inserted as parameter.  For example I have **var myname="mysteryboy";** so  when i run/call the method **myname.substring(2)** then  substring method  create new string from the index 2 and leave all the character before 2 index.

Answer (score 3):

[`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) returns:

> the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string

In your example we are looking for the last `\` in the path and then taking the next part in the path which is the file name.